# unetsim: Is there a functionality to move a node from one coordinate to another by specifying the coordinates only and not velocity or direction?

Tags: unetstack

I'm trying to move a mobile AUV (node) on a particular path by specifying coordinates in the form of (x,y,z). As far as I have explored, UnetSim only offers nodes to move by specifying velocity and directions. Is there any way to make a node move to a particular set of locations in order after being deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MobilityModel` in UnetSim Nodes has a mechanism to define piece-wise location information for various times in the Simulation.

The `node.motionModel` property is a `List` of `HashMap`s which can contain any of the following keys:

- `time`: Time at which the mobility action is valid.
- `location`: Coordinates (`[-50.m, -50.m, 0]`).
- `speed` : Speed in mps (`1.mps`).
- `heading` : Heading in degrees (`30.deg`).
- `turnRate`: Rate of turn (`1.dps`).
- `diveRate`: Rate of diving (`-0.1.mps`).

So using the `time` and `location` key we can achieve what you are trying to do.

The UnetIDE comes bundled with an [example for simulating mobility](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/tree/master/samples/mobility). In this example, there are 4 sub-examples of various ways mobility can be simulated.

The [3rd example, Triangular motion (with diving)](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/blob/master/samples/mobility/mobility.groovy#L55), can be easily updated to indicate coordinates at various points of time during the simulation as follow.

```
println 'Simulation AUV-3: Triangular motion (with dive)'
simulate 15.minutes, {
  def n = node('AUV-3', location: [-50.m, -50.m, 0], mobility: true)
  n.startup = trackAuvLocation
  n.motionModel = [[time:  0.minutes, location: [-50.m, -50.m, 0] ],
                   [time:  3.minutes, location: [-100.m, -50.m, 0] ],
                   [time:  4.minutes, location: [-100.m, -100.m, 0] ],
                   [time:  7.minutes, location: [-50.m, -100.m, 0] ],
                   [time:  10.minutes, location: [-50.m, -50.m, 0] ]]

}
```

This will give the following plot if plotted using the [plot-tracks.groovy](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/blob/master/samples/mobility/plot-tracks.groovy) tool.

[image: auv-tracks]

Comment: I think this should solve my problem! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer so other users can find this useful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers